# Kubernetes - How to make simple Linux container Image without App Running permanently

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I need to make my Linux container running (without any app or service in it) so I can enter /bin/bash and modify some local linux files before I actually **manually** run my app from the container shell (this is  purely for some debugging purposes so I do not want any modifications in my image itself, please do not suggest that as an option)

I have defined my Kubernetes YAML file hoping that I would be able to execute simple `command: ["/bin/bash"]` but this does not work because it will execute command and Exit the container. So how I can make it not to exit so I am able to `exec` container?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontarena-ads-deployment2
  labels:
    app: frontarena-ads-deployment2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: frontarena-ads-aks-test2
      labels:
        app: frontarena-ads-aks-test2
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        "beta.kubernetes.io/os": linux
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
      - name: frontarena-ads-aks-test2
        image: test.dev/ads:test2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: DB_TYPE
          value: "odbc"
        - name: LANG
          value: "en_US.utf8"
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: fa-repo-secret
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontarena-ads-aks-test2
```

When I want to see what is going on after the deployment I can notice:

```
NAME                                                      READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
frontarena-ads-deployment2-546fc4b75-zmmrs                0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   19         77m
```

**`kubectl logs $POD`** doesn't return anything
and `kubectl describe pod $POD` output is:

```
Command:
  /bin/bash
State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       Completed
  Exit Code:    0
  Started:      Wed, 07 Apr 2021 11:40:31 +0000
  Finished:     Wed, 07 Apr 2021 11:40:31 +0000
```

Comment: have you looked at the concepts of [`Init-containers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) useful for these tasks of setting up stuff before starting the main container?

Comment: I'd try `docker run --rm -it test.dev/ads:test2 bash` on a local system, rather than trying to debug the image build in the remote environment.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks David but local system does not have all the network connections towards the database configured because of Security and because it is in Azure so this particular case which you mentioned is not applicable but thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to run some long/endless process for the container to be up. For example you can read a stream, that'll last forever unless you kill the pod/container:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
args: ["cat /dev/stdout"]
```

Comment: Thank you.
Also I succeeded to find that also it's possible to do with this as well:
        `command: ["tail"]
        args: ["-f","/dev/null"]`
It might be as well useful for someone. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreyDonald that's just another example of an endless task :)